# How to set an instance of CKEDitor on the page to be always Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ckeditor, dotnetnuke

I have been working on the DNN site (ASP.NET, C#, Visual Basic, Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web) that uses CKEditor on the page. The example is:

```
<dnn:TextEditor ID="txtRichBox" runat="server" Width="850" TextRenderMode="Raw" HtmlEncode="False" defaultmode="Rich" height="350" Visible="false" choosemode="true" chooserender="False" />
```

I would like to have only Rich Text Editor on the page, not Basic Text Box. How can I do that? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just invent properties like `choosemode` and `chooserender` and expect it to work. The Editor has a [limited number of properties](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/text-editor-control).

The easiest way is to hide the radio buttons `Basic Text Box` and `Rich Text Editor` with CSS so users can't switch between them. By default the Editor is loaded, not the underlying basic TextBox.

```
<style>
    .dnnTextPanelView {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a god idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript to attach CKEditor to the control :

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'ID of textbox control' );
</script>
```

Might I recommend the documentation for CKEditor?  It's [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation).

Comment: Thank you @DrMistry for your help and attention. I would like to find a way to write a jQuery for example that will trigger event for Rich Box. thank you in advance for any help for this.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.  What event do you want to use as the trigger, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit confusing. I mean for example $("#dnnControlId").Load() or something similar, and in event set Rich Text Editor instead of Basic Text Box. On the other side, my approach is maybe wrong. Maybe there is a way to set Rich Text Box somewhere in the config file of editor. Thank you again.

Comment: OP uses a build-in DNN Control of CKEditor. It works a bit different. Fixed the tags...